# How do I draw two lines that intersect on Bitmap - Java android

Tags: java, android, canvas, draw

So I want to draw two lines that cross in the middle (like an x), and I want to draw this onto my randomly generated bitmap. Does anyone know how I can make the line diagonl?

public static Bitmap randomImage(int width, int height) {

```
    Bitmap ranImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int r = rand.nextInt(255);
            int g = rand.nextInt(255);
            int b = rand.nextInt(255);
            int color = Color.rgb(r, g, b);
            ranImage.setPixel(x, y, color);
        }
    //initialise a new canvas instance
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(ranImage);

        //intialise a new paint instance to draw the line
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    //line color
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    //line width in pixels
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    //set a pizel value to offset the line from the canvas edge
    int offset = 50;




    //draw a line on canvas at the center postion ....for now
    canvas.drawLine(
            offset,
            canvas.getHeight()/2,
            canvas.getWidth()-offset,
            canvas.getHeight()/2,
            paint
    );
    

    return ranImage;
}
```